# How to make a div centered, text to the left and photo to the right

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to make a paragraph and a photo inline like this one [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox Module can achieve that easily.

CSS:

```
#profile {
display: flex;
}
#bio {
flex: 2;
margin-right: 2px;
/*
other rules for bio here
*/
}
#photo {
flex: 1;
/*
other rules for photo here
*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="profile">
<section id="bio">
<p>Bio Text</p>
</section>
<section id="photo">
<img src="user_profile_photo.jpg" alt="User Photo" />
</section>
</section>
```

alternatively, you can use 'display: table' for '#profile' and 'display: table-cell' for '#bio' & '#photo'.

Answer (score 0):

To get the content centered, you should specify the max-width of the container holding your content and set the margin to auto.

You could try putting both in the same div and then in CSS using `float: right;` for the image and `float: left;` for the text?

If you don't want to keep fiddling with values in CSS, you could use the Bootstrap framework and do:

```
<div class="summary">
  <p class="col-md-9">[text here]</p>
  <img class="col-md-3" src="[image source]"/>
</div>
```

and then play around with the 9 and 3 to get the width of the columns how you want them